# Eclipse IDE inserting line breaks by formatting DATA.SQL file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I did some data insertion into DATA.SQL in Spring Boot and by Eclipse IDE manual formatting (Ctrl+Shift+F seems to not work in SQL files in Eclipse) and it is inserting these break lines in the database, how to avoid it?

```
INSERT INTO table(valueA, valueB) VALUES   
('valueA
','valueB');
```

Json Output:

```
{"valueA":"valueA\n","valueB":" valueB\n","valueB"}
```

Comment: the quotation marks are in next line

Comment: @SaurabhVerma The inserts are well bigger than that one, made to exemplify, not readable in one line, that's the way I formated like this, so that's no way, right?